# Dynamic page title for laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How can I get my post title's as my page title?

```
@section('title', '| {{ $post->title }}')
```

This will return php code in my page title!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single quotes from the value you are rendering as this is just outputting a string:

```
@section('title', $post->title)
```

Comment: No problem. If you want to add the bar at the start you can use string concatenation: `'| '.$post->title`. Please remember to accept an answer :)